# Need to merge a sparse matrix and two columns from data frame in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf

I have a sparse matrix with (881900, 76656) .

[Sprase matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95FLe.png)

[Dataframe with column(highlighted) of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a49mU.png)

Both my dataframe and sparse matrix have the same number of rows, but have no columns in common. The sparse matrix is my output from tf-idf process of sentiment analysis

Can you please guide me if I can merge these two objects in python, when merging, I think I should ensure that every entry from data frame is aligned with corresponding entry of sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate these into a sparse matrix using the `sparse.hstack` function from scipy sparse. Here's an example:

```py
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

s = sparse.csc_matrix(np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2))

display(s.toarray())
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5]])
display(df.values)
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])

combined = sparse.hstack([s, df])
display(combined.toarray())
# array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
#        [3, 4, 5, 2, 3]])
```